# checking database from webservice netbeans

Tags: web-services, netbeans, mybatis

sorry if my question confusing cause this is the first time i make a question. if there is something that i can do to make it clearer, just tell me so i can improve the way i'm asking.

currently i'm trying to make web service from netbeans that can check some data from database. Because i'm newbie so i followed tutorial from 
http://programmerguru.com/webservice-tutorial/how-to-create-java-webservice-in-netbeans/ to make the web service.

but when i trying to check the database with my usual way with mybattis, it keep in give me java.lang.nulpointerexception. when i try to debug it, it give me "variable information not available, source compiled without -g option" and throw me to InvocationTargetException.java

```
 public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
    super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
    this.target = target;
}
```

here is the code for the web service

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project                  
 Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
 package com.bismillah.berkah;

import com.bismillah.berkah.dao.DummyDao;
import com.bismillah.berkah.daoImpl.DummyDaoImpl;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

/**
 *
 * @author Ari
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "Check4Update")
public class Check4Update {
    public DummyDaoImpl ddi;

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     *
     * @param InTerminalNumber
     * @return
     */
@WebMethod(operationName = "CheckUpdate")
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "InTerminalNumber") String InTerminalNumber) {

    String OutError = "";
    String OutMessage = "";
    if (InTerminalNumber == null) {
        return "InTerminalNumber can't be null";
    } else {

        Map mapdao = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put("InTerminalNumber", InTerminalNumber);
        mapdao = ddi.check4UpdatePatch(map);

        OutError = (String) mapdao.get("OutError");
        OutMessage = (String) mapdao.get("OutMessage");
        return "Error : " + OutError + ", with message : " + OutMessage;

    }

}

public void setDdi(DummyDaoImpl ddi) {
    this.ddi = ddi;
}


}
```

and here is the code mybattis impl

```
package com.bismillah.berkah.daoImpl;

import com.bismillah.berkah.Check4Update;
import com.bismillah.berkah.config.MyBatisConnectionFactory;
import com.bismillah.berkah.dao.*;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author Ari
 */
public class DummyDaoImpl 
{

private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

public DummyDaoImpl()
{
    sqlSessionFactory = MyBatisConnectionFactory.getSqlSessionFactory();
}

public Map check4UpdatePatch(Map map)
{

    Check4Update c4u = new Check4Update();
    c4u.setDdi(this);
    SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    try
    {
        session.selectOne("dummy.check4UpdatePatch", map);

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.toString();
    } finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
    return map;

}

}
```

could you tell me how to fix it? so i can get the data? by the way i always get thrown at my web service, here exactly

```
mapdao = ddi.check4UpdatePatch(map);
```

once again sorry if my question confusing cause this is the first time i make a question. if there is something that i can do to make it clearer, just tell me so i can improve the way i'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

sorry already found the problem, it is cause wrong configuration on mybatis.
i haven't change my string resource on MyBatisConnectionFactory, also the one at xml file.

maybe that's why i always get java lang nul.

actually when i trying to fix this, i make some interface class too, but still not working until i find my problem. if anyone have some problem like me maybe you can fix it with adding some interface so the impl will override the interface.